# Android ExoPlayer not playing on Asus Zenfone 2 running Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, exoplayer

My video player is not playing on Asus Zenfone 2 running Android Marshmallow. I don't know if it's a problem with the caching library or ExoPlayer.

My code is as follows -

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelectorvideoTrackSelectionFactory);
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
mBetterVideoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
mBetterVideoPlayer.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
mBetterVideoPlayer.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
HttpProxyCacheServer proxy = AppBaseApplication.getProxy(NewWorkoutVideoActivity.this);
proxy.registerCacheListener(NewWorkoutVideoActivity.this, current.getVideo());
proxyUrl = proxy.getProxyUrl(current.getVideo());
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getApplicationContext(),Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"));
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(proxyUrl));
exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
```

Comment: `I don't know if it's a problem with the caching library or ExoPlayer.` then you should find it out first. Try excluding the caching library, and check if the player will work

Comment: The issue was reported by a client. I am not able to replicate the same on the devices that I have @VladMatvienko

Comment: Have you tried this on other devices?

Comment: @AnkitMehta yup, works on all Android Versions on the physical devices that I have.